# superuser can't open gnome-terminal (Can't open display error)

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, webserver, 22.10

Recently I've been using ubuntu on my old laptop to host a web server (I'm using ubuntu desktop 22.10). 
The problem is when I insert the command `gnome-terminal -- sh /home/user/server.sh` to start the servers, I get this error: `Argument parsing failed: can't open display:`  (or something like that cause it's in another language). 
However, when I start the terminal with a normal user, everything goes fine. I need to automatically start the servers with systemctl so I can't run it without superuser. What should I do? [image: Here is a screenshot of the error in the terminal (the error is in Italian and I can't translate)]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Are you issuing this command over SSH? If so, it may not be necessary to use `gnome-terminal` as you're already where you need to be to issue commands 

Comment: Why would you want to open a terminal to run a command instead of simply opening a terminal in the regular way and then running `sudo /home/user/server.sh`? Or, if with systemctl, just `/home/user/server.sh`. What is the graphical terminal (`gnome-terminal`) doing as part of this pipeline?

Comment: I am using the command over SSH because i get the same identical error when the service starts in ubuntu and i wanted to see what was the problem. My goal is to have 2 windows of the graphical terminal open each one for an instance of peerjs, which is a nodejs package, so i need to keep the terminal open to keep it alive.

Comment: You will need to disclose the contents of "servers.sh" because anyone can say something sensible about the issue.

Comment: in server.sh there is just the command to start the server, nothing else. The command is `peerjs -p 8080`, which is to start peerjs library. The error has nothing to do with the file, only with the `gnome-terminal` command.